# How to splitting a list of vectors to small lists in decreasing order in r

Tags: r

Suppose I have a function which returns me a list of several vectors. Assume that I would like to split this list to small lists of different numbers of vectors. The number of the vectors in each list is different from one list to another. I need to create these lists in a decreasing order.

### Genearal example:

Suppose I have `n` variables. Then, `k = n:2`. My function will return me a list of `n(n-1)/2` vectors. Then, the number of the new sub-lists is `n - 1`. Hence, I need to have `n-1` different lists. The number of the vectors in each list is `J = 1:k-1`.

### Numerical example:

If `n=4`, then, `k=4, 3, 2`, then, `J=3,2,1`. Hence, my function will return me 6 vectors. These vectors should be stored into different lists. The number of the vectors in each list is based on `J`. Hence, I will have 3 different lists as follows:

- 3 vectors in the first list.
- 2 vectors in the second list.
- one vector in the last list.

In other words, the returned list (the output of my function) should be split into sub-lists in a decreasing order based on `J`.

My function is very complicated. Hence, I will provide a list of 6 vectors as the output of my function.

Suppose my function return me the following list:

```
x <- list(x1=c(1,2,3), x2=c(1,4,3), x3=c(3,4,6), x4=c(4,8,4), x5=c(4,33,4), x6=c(9,6,7))
```

How I can split it into sub-lists as described above? The excepted output is:

```
x_sub1 <- list(x1=c(1,2,3), x2=c(1,4,3), x3=c(3,4,6))
x_sub2 <- list(x4=c(4,8,4), x5=c(4,33,4))
x_sub3 <- list(x6=c(9,6,7))
```

I tried this:

```
x_sub <- list()
for(j in 1:(k-1)){
    x_sub[[j]] <- x[[i]]
    }
```

and of course, it is not what I expected.

Any idea, please? How I generate it for an arbitrary number of vectors? for example, how I can apply the split idea over `n` vectors?

Many thanks for all helps.

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear to me

Comment: @MrFlick, thank you so much. This is a typo. I will edit it.

Comment: @akrun Thank you so much for your comment and answer. I just meant how I can generate it to the `n` number of vectors. Then, I found that you delete your answer. I am really so sorry if I misunderstand you.

Comment: @akrun I am always proud of your work. It is correct. I really surprised why someone downvoted it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use `rep` to `split` the `list` into a `list` of `lists`

```
lst <- split(x, rep(paste0("x_sub", 1:3), 3:1))
```

and extract the nested `list` with the name

```
lst[["x_sub1"]]
```

It is better not to create multiple objects in the global environment.  But, if it is needed, then use `list2env`

```
list2env(lst, envir = .GlobalEnv)
x_sub1
#$x1
#[1] 1 2 3

#$x2
#[1] 1 4 3

#$x3
#[1] 3 4 6
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. So what about for `n` vectors. Can I use `lst <- split(x, rep(paste0("x_sub", 1:n), n:1))`. Also, I have edited my question, if you would like to have a look. Thank you again.

Comment: @Maryam In the question, the input is a `list` 'x'

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- list(x1=c(1,2,3), x2=c(1,4,3), x3=c(3,4,6),
          x4=c(4,8,4), x5=c(4,33,4),
          x6=c(9,6,7))
```

You can try the function `split()` to partition your list `x` by certain format. I don't understand what you mean for `n`, `k`, `J`, so you need to define them by yourself. I just simply set `J` as `1:3`.

```
J <- 1:3
breaks <- rep(J, rev(J)) # [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3
y <- split(x, f = breaks)
names(y) <- paste0("x_sub", J)
list2env(y, envir = .GlobalEnv)

x_sub1
x_sub2
x_sub3
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. `n`,`k`, and `J` are just numbers that help me to define the number of my list and their number of vectors.