# How to split a list of vectors to sub-lists by increasing order.

Tags: r

I have a list of `n` vectors. I would like to split it to sub-list where the number of the vectors at each list is different. The number of the vectors is increased sequentially from one list to another. For example, 
if I have a list with `6` vectors. Then, I would like to split it to several list as follows:

The first list contains one vector. Then, the second list contains 2 vectors and so on. For example,

Suppose I have the list `x` as follows:

```
x <- list(x1=c(1,2,3), x2=c(1,4,3), x3=c(3,4,6), x4=c(4,8,4), x5=c(4,33,4), x6=c(9,6,7))
```

Then, I would like to split it into 3 lists,

```
list1 = x1
list2 = list(x2, x3)
list3 = list(x4,x5, x6)
```

I have similar question ([How to splitting a list of vectors to small lists in decreasing order in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53246123/how-to-splitting-a-list-of-vectors-to-small-lists-in-decreasing-order-in-r)) but in a decreasing order.

How I can generate it to arbitrary number of vectors. For example, how if I have 10 or 20 vectors?

Any idea, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd stick them all in a list of lists

```
MyLists <- list()
i <- 1
for (inc in 1:3){
  MyLists[[inc]] <- x[i:(i+inc-1)]
  i <- i+inc
}
```

Now `MyLists[[1]]` is `list1`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Building off farnsy's answer, If you need each list in a separate indexed list in the global environment you could do something like this.

```
#your Stater list
x <- list(x1=c(1,2,3), x2=c(1,4,3), x3=c(3,4,6), 
          x4=c(4,8,4), x5=c(4,33,4), x6=c(9,6,7))


#using a paste parse eval approach to evaluate a string
i<-1
for(inc in 1:3){
  eval(parse(text =
      paste0("list", inc, "<-list(",
         paste0("x$",names(x)[i:(i+inc-1)],collapse = ","),
         ")")
  ))

  i <- i+inc
}
```